# sap.m.UploadCollection shows the temporary upload item just for the first upload

Tags: sapui5

I used `sap.m.UploadCollection` to upload some files. Everything works well except one temporary item that is shown for the first item that I try to upload. 
As soon as I upload one file it will not shown anymore for the second file until I refresh the page. When I refresh the page and try to upload the next file it will shown again just one time. 
It seems I could have to clean some history of the control but I don't know what I have to do after successful upload to make it visible for the next time that I try to upload a file.

Here is a picture on the upload indicator that I speak about.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you set the `uploadUrl` in your `sap.m.UploadCollection.onChange` event, you have to set it to null in your `sap.m.UploadCollection.onUploadComplete` event.

```
onUploadComplete: function(oEvent) {
        var oUploadCollection = oEvent.getSource();
        oUploadCollection.setUploadUrl(null);
}
```